# Oleum concentration description

Tags: concentration

What is the meaning of "free" $\ce{SO3}$ and "combined" $\ce{SO3}$ in the oleum sample concentration description?

Also what are these maximum and minimum values of % labelling in oleum sample?

Comment: There is virtually no SO3 molecules in oleum, as they are strongly Lewis acidic.

Comment: Guys, I don't understand how this question is unclear. The question makes sense. And to consider, the asker can only ask about the terms that they have learnt.

Comment: _sigh_ I _guess_ this "combined" is SO3 + H2O and free the rest as if there was just H2SO4 and SO3 unreacted which isn't true.

Comment: The English wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleum) is not discerning "free" and "combined" $\ce{SO3}$, still working with fuming $\ce{H2SO4}$ with 30% and  >60% $\ce{SO3}$ (http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/778990?lang=en&region=US) keeps a mark.

Comment: I also think this should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term combined "$\ce{SO3}$" is nothing but $\ce{SO3}$ of $\ce{(SO3 + H2O)}$ and free $\ce{SO3}$ means that is $\ce{SO3}$ in oleum sample.

And value of % leveling of oleum is from (100% to 122.5%).

Comment: Why is the upper limit 122.5%?